# Is shiny a good solution to display a computationally intensive fixed big dataset?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

**Here is my problem:**
I have a big dataset that in R that represent an object of ~500MB that I plot with ggplot2.
There is 20 millions *num* values to plot along an *int* axis that are associated with a 5 level *factor* for color aesthetics.
I would like to set up a webapps where users could visualize this dataset, using different filter that rely on the factor to display all the data are once or for example a subset corresponding to 1 level of the factor.
The problem is that when I write the plot it takes a couple of minute (~10 minutes)

**Solution 1 :** The best one for the user would be to use Shiny UI. But is there a way to have the plot already somehow prewritten thanks to ggplot2 or shiny tricks so it can be quickly displayed?

**Solution 2 :** Without shiny, I would have done different plots of the dataset already and I will have to rebuild a UI to let user visualizes the different pictures. If I do that I will have to restrict the possible use cases of displaying the data.

Looking forward for advices and discussions

Comment: If it takes 10 minutes to do your plot. Your shiny app will load during 10 minutes each time you change the input. So it's not very good... Except if your plot does'nt depends of user's inputs, you can just load a PNG file.

Comment: You shouldnt need to plot anything this big really. If you;re getting the data from a database then just write a sequence of queries that will aggregate the data on the DB side and drag very little data to output in `shiny`. Seems to be a bad design on your part.

Comment: @Smich7 This is actually an interesting hybrid solution to use shiny to display picture, I'll think about that. But it is a bit an overkill to use shiny for that

Comment: @PorkChop I agree. There is actually overplotting here, but this representation has to follow some rules and I cannot transform data.

Comment: I have a dirty trick in mind. Replace over-plotting by geom_rect() and remove those data points.

Comment: @PorkChop I would waste my time doing something interactive instead of  rendering static files. Nevertheless, you answered the question. If you feel like doing an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you shouldn't need to plot anything this big really. If you're getting the data from a database then just write a sequence of queries that will aggregate the data on the DB side and drag very little data to output in `shiny`. Seems to be a bad design on your part.

That being said, the author of `highcharter` package did work on implementing `boost.js module` to help with plotting millions of points. https://rpubs.com/jbkunst/highcharter-boost.

Also have a look at the `bigvis` package, which allows '*Exploratory data analysis for large datasets (10-100 million observations)'* and has been built by @Hadley Wickham   https://github.com/hadley/bigvis. There is a nice presentation about the package [at this meetup](http://files.meetup.com/1406240/bigvis.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Think about following procedure:

With `ggplot2` you can produce an R object.

```
plot_2_save <- ggplot()
```

an object can be saved by

```
saveRDS(object, "file.rds")
```

and in the shiny `server.R` you can load this data

```
plot_from_data <- readRDS("path/.../file.rds")
```

I used this setup for some kind of text classification with a really (really) huge svm model implemented as an application on shiny-server.

Comment: The problem here is not the ggplot object but in the time it takes to render the plot